# Calling Python variables within a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Consider I have three lists, stored in file `sports.py`, which is separate from the .py file I'm working in:

```
games_1 = ["Tennis", …]
games_2 = ["Cricket", …] 
games_3 = ["Golf", …]
```

I also have a variable `var_game == "Football"`.

I would like to check which lists `var_game` appears in. 
So far I have tried:

```
for N in range(1,3):
    if var_game in sports.games_N:
        gamesN_check = 1
    else:
        gamesN_check = 0
```

However, Python does not let me use N to cycle through the lists in this way. How do I need to use it with the correct syntax?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `dictionary`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend packaging your lists in a dictionary and evaluating in the manner below:

```
games_1 = ['Tennis', 'Football', 'Basketball']
games_2 = ['Cricket', 'Football', 'Lacrosse'] 
games_3 = ['Golf','Baseball', 'Rugby', 'Track'] 

games_N = {'games_1': games_1, 'games_2': games_2, 'games_3': games_3}

var_game = 'Football'

games_N_check = {key: 1 if var_game in val else 0 for key, val in games_N.items()}
```

Outputs:

```
{'games_1': 1, 'games_2': 1, 'games_3': 0}
```

**Additionally**

A quick means to create your dictionary from a series of lists, so that you do not have to explicitly name every list:

```
games_lists = [['Tennis', 'Football', 'Basketball'],['Cricket', 'Football', 'Lacrosse'],['Golf','Baseball', 'Rugby', 'Track']]

games_N = {'games_{}'.format(idx+1): game_list for idx, game_list in enumerate(games_lists)}
```

Gives:

```
{'games_1': ['Tennis', 'Football', 'Basketball'], 'games_2': ['Cricket', 'Football', 'Lacrosse'], 'games_3': ['Golf', 'Baseball', 'Rugby', 'Track']}
```

Comment: This worked excellently for me, and allows the scaling up to more than 3 lists that I will need later. I wasn't aware of the dictionary function in Python (yes, I'm really that new to it). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3 variables for games, Why don't you make a list of list of games

```
games = [["Tennis", …], ["Cricket", …], ["Golf", …]]
```

and a list of results

```
games_check = []
```

And then check for every `game in games`, if `var_games in game`, and if so - add `0` to the list of results `games_check`, otherwise add `1`

```
for game in games:
    if var_game in game:
        games_check.append(1)
    else:
        games_check.append(0)
```

Or to make it more 'Pythonic'

```
games_check = [(1 if var_game in game else 0) for game in games]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think for your situation, you can just do this:

```
if var_game in sports.games_1:
    games1_check = 1
elif var_game in sports.games_2:
    games2_check = 1
elif var_game in sports.games_3:
    games3_check = 1
```

Comment: What's the use of the for loop then?